# Summing up only numbers in an argument

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to sum up only numbers that is merge with alphabets inside an argument in javascript

```
function getSum(){}
 getSum("1ha","22rr","33y",44) => the output will be like this 100
```

I have tried this but this is not the expected result

```
 function getSum () {
   return Array.from(arguments).reduce((sum, value) => {
   if (Array.isArray(value)) {
     sum += getSum.apply(this, value)
   } else {
   sum += Number(value)
 }

  return sum
 }, 0)
}
```

Can someone help me with this please!

Comment: Could you describe what the signature of this function should look like? It looks like you want to support nested arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a reduction after using `match()` on each argument:

```js
function getSum() {
    return Array.from(arguments).map(x => x.toString().match(/\d+/))
                                .reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + parseInt(a), 0);
}

var output = getSum("1ha", "22rr", "33y", 44);
console.log(output);
```